# Detect App Killed or Terminated in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to insert data to local database when user terminates the app. So far, I found `AppLifecycleState` but the there's no equivalent for state when App Killed (the closest to it is `AppLifecycleState.paused` but the execution is more like `onActivityPaused` in Android).

Is it possible to detect user when terminate the app? If it's possible, how can I do so? Any help would be so appreciated, thank you!